# How to fix "sys.stderr is None" after compiled a script with Pyinstaller --noconsole?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

**ENVIRONMENT**

Windows 10

Python 3.10

Pyinstaller 5.9

**PROBLEM:**

I am trying to compile a script that needs to run some command lines in the console in order to get some values from the system.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    faulthandler.enable()
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(p_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        output, errors = proc.communicate()
    except:
        pass
```

You can use this code above to reproduce the error.

When I compile with the console, the "exe" works fine.
When I compile with "--noconsole", the "exe" failed with this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 5432, in <module>
    faulthandler.enable()
RuntimeError: sys.stderr is None
```

After a few hours of investigation, I've understood the stdin and stdout arguments from the code "subprocess.Popen) can't be used with "--noconsole" compilation mode.
I tried this solution :

```
stream = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = stream
sys.stderr = stream
```

But it still doesn't work.
I verified the doc:
https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyinstaller/downloads/pdf/stable/
It clearly said :

> (Windows) In windowed/noconsole mode, stop setting sys.stdout and
> sys.stderr to custom NullWriter object, and instead leave them at
> None. This matches the behavior of windowed python interpreter
> (pythonw. exe) and prevents interoperability issues with code that
> (rightfully) expects the streams to be either None or objects that are
> fully compatible with io.IOBase. (#3503)

So the solution N°1 seems correct, doesn't it?

I didn't have this issue last year when I compiled the previous version. I don't understand why now there is this issue.

Does anyone have any solution to this issue PLEASE?

Comment: Can't you set `stderr=subprocesss.PIPE` as well?

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts I edited my code, compiled, and executed it. Same error: https://prnt.sc/2zSi_V1-b1KX

Comment: What is `faulthandler`?  I don't see why you think this problem is related to `subprocess`.

Comment: I update the post to add more lines of code. Sorry, I didn't think of it before. It is the first line of my main code : faulthandler.enable() (see new code above)

Comment: Why are you trying to enable functionality to print tracebacks to stderr on fault, when you have no stderr?

Comment: And where did you place the code that sets `sys.stderr = stream`?

Comment: I don't remember why I needed it. It is a very long code of 3 years old. I need to do the maintenance. I can't start from scratch. Anyway, when I isolate this piece of code and compiled it, I still get this error "sys.stderr is None".  These 3 lines of code "sys.stderr = stream" are above the "proc = subprocess.Popen..." line.

Comment: The `proc = ...` line isn't the problem line. The `faulthandler.enable()` line is the problem line. You put the `sys.stder = ...` line after the code that needed it.

Comment: Thanks, but am not sure I get it. I removed faulthandler.enable() and it worked. Would you mind to explain a bit more in an "Answer" and I 'll validate it.

Comment: We don't know what `faulthandler` is, but apparently IT requires access to stdout.  Therefore, if your process doesn't have a stdout, you need to PROVIDE one before you call `faulthandler`.  That's the diagnosis and the solution.

Comment: "You can use this code above to reproduce the error."  <-- No we cannot.  What is `faulthandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are running into a RuntimeError because sys.stderr is None. The faulthandler module needs a valid stderr stream to report errors. This can occur when your Python script is executed in an environment where the standard error stream (sys.stderr) is not properly set up or is missing.

To fix this issue, you can try one of the following:

Set up a valid stderr stream before enabling the faulthandler:

```
import sys
import os
import faulthandler
import subprocess

if sys.stderr is None:
    sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    faulthandler.enable()
    try:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(p_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
        output, errors = proc.communicate()
    except:
        pass
```

Alternatively, if you want to see the error output, you can set sys.stderr to sys.stdout:

```
if sys.stderr is None:
    sys.stderr = sys.stdout
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling faulthandler enables to execute correctly the .exe file created by Pyinstaller.